# JSSOR - keep current slider position after every web page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

I am just installed beautifull Jssor Slider called "Nested slider" (sources can be downloaded for free from web page: http://www.jssor.com/demos/nested-slider.html).

Could you please advice how can I get the following behaviour:

Every main slider and subsliders contains quite lot of images which run in slideshow process. 
I would need possibility to keep slideshow continuesly even if it will be disturbed by web page refresh (for example when customer will change product, etc).
In practice, when slideshow would be on second position "Motor" and Image number 7 and web page would be refreshed I want, that after page refresh,  the cutomer would keep watching this slideshow begining from this 2nd positoin "Motor" and image number 7. Currently, after every web page refresh the slideshow starts from the beginning, it means from 1st position "Landscape" and image number 1.

Is that would have to affect cookies somehow ? 
Is that very hard to implement ? 
I would be thankfull for exact code which would be ready to go.

Kind Regards,
Ben

Comment: SO is not a code writing service that provides "exact code which would be great to go". Show your effort by adding what you have tried so far. Refer [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Provided link direct to the web page when everybody can see and download script code for free. The Jssor support re-direct to ask a question on Stack Overflow. Unfortunatelly I don't have any further details. My efforts was just review Stack Overflow database and I found that there is no solution for my problem yet.

Comment: Oh thanks for the info. I didn't know that JSSOR has support here. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2110412/jssor) is the JSSOR support user. They should help you out soon they seem active. Good Luck

Answer (score 3):

There is an option $StartIndex which enables you display a specified slide of a slider at the beginning.

```
var options = {
    ...
    $StartIndex: lastviewed_slide_index,    //Index of slide to display when initialize, default value is 0
    ...
};
```

Given the nested slider example, you can use the following statements to retrieve last viewed index.

```
var main_slider_lastviewed_index = jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex();
var child_slider_lastviewed_index = nestedSliders[main_slider_lastviewed_index].$CurrentIndex();
```

Comment: When I put mentioned code than all slider stops working. I can see only first main image. 
Does lastviewed_slide_index is built in function ?

Comment: Just tell you the way to do. You need to write your own code to implement this feature.

Comment: Thank you for right direction. If I would be the coder, probably I would complete this task quickly. Unfortunatelly I don't have an idea how to use your feedback. If you would be so kind, I would be very thanfull for more details. I believe that this would help aslo to the others.

Comment: You can use url parameter or cookie to do this job.